# Why is my web app scrolling super slow on iOS (Chrome and Safari), but ok on all other platforms?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, scroll, safari

Scrolling is practically impossible on iOS browsers Safari and Chrome, a few pixels only per scroll attempt. On any other platform tested, scrolling is smooth and fast.

Edit: The issue only appears in iOS 13.

App is available [here](https://aidu-action-dev-01.firebaseapp.com).

The app is angular based.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting similar problems, this is what I had to adjust:

- Remove the youtube IFrame (
- Remove :hover based styling of big divs (somehow the hover event eat up the scrolling motion)

These 2 measures fixed the issue. However, this is temporary only and I will at a later point have to figure out how to re-implement the 2 features without losing scrollability.